# How to copy a range in excel via vba with variable column

Tags: vba, variables

I'm beginner on excel and vba.

I want to select and copy range via `vba` code having this situation:
`Rang (A1:B[x])` such that 'x' is the value of cell "C1".
what is the proper syntax?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to get the value of `C1`:

```
myLine = Cells(1, 3).Value
```

Note: `Cells(1, 3)` is `C1`.

Then you can concat this as address for your range:

```
Range("A1:B" & myLine).Select
```